# Asp.NET MVC3 Application Error using Active Reports 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have a MVC3 app which works 100% on localhost, however, when I deploy the application, and upon accessing the Reports (by the way, I am using ActiveReports 6) i get "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." Any help? does this have to do with the autentication or folder permissions?

EDIT:
I have a standard license of Active Report without the WebViewer. Hence, I export the report to PDF and then send it to the browser via Response.BinaryWrite(memStream);